# Remove specific occurence from string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a variable called `$name` that contains the name of a project.  In most cases, the name takes the following form

```
OCT16: Some Project
```

However, it is not always in this format, sometimes it does not have the month/year prefix.

What I am attempting to do is this.  If it does have the prefix MMMYY: then I need to remove this part from the name.  Now I know I could probably use something like `preg_replace` to remove this particular pattern from a string, but how do I check that it has this pattern in the first place?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try using `preg_replace('~\d{6}$~', '', $s)` to remove 6 digits at the end of the string.

Comment: As I stated, it does not always start like this so I need to check first

Comment: Why check if `preg_replace` also performs the check before replacing? If no match occurs, `preg_replace` returns the unchanged string.

Comment: Do you know what regex I would need to test against?

Comment: `sometimes it does not have the month/year prefix`. Does that mean it could be `OCT: Some Project`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
$project_name = 'OCT16: Some Project';
$project_name = preg_replace("/\b[A-Z]{3,4}\d{2}:\s?/u", "", $project_name);

print_r($project_name);  // "Some Project"

// another test case:
$project_name = ' Some Project OCT16: some text';
....
print_r($project_name);  // "Some Project some text"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression should actually be the following:

```
(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\d{2}:\s?
```

and `preg_replace` will just return the original string if it does not find a match.